# ActiveAdmin -- not saving has_many records in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have two models `store` and `category`. A store can have many categories and should get stored in `categories_stores` table. The model relationships are setup properly and I have the following on the store form:

`f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes`

And they do indeed display correctly. But creating or editing a store doesn't create / delete those records in the `categories_stores` table.

Any ideas?

**Update:** The above code *already* generates the list correctly (see screenshot and HTML code below) -- the only problem is changes to this aren't getting saved in the DB!

[image]

```
<input id = "merchant_category_ids_" name="merchant[category_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<ol>
    <li><input id="merchant_category_ids_1" name="merchant[category_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="6" /> Clothing</li>
    <li><input checked="checked" id="merchant_category_ids_2" name="merchant[category_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="5" /> Electronics</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may be trying to set sub-resources. If that's the case, you can try something like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :categories do |f_categories| %>
    <%= f_categories.input ... %>
<% end %>
```

Take a look at the `fields_for` [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) for more info.

Comment: Well I'm able to generate the list of categories correctly (and the ones that exist in the joining table for that record are indeed checked by default). It's just that saving the main record doesn't update or change the joining table.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but have you made sure that the following is defined in the respective models?

```
attr_accessible :categories_stores_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories_stores
```